# PHP foreach - show line breaks in source code

Tags: php, foreach

I'm currently using the following PHP foreach code below. When I view the source code, it's a giant block of list items.

My question is, how can I edit this so each list item in the source code is on it's own line for easier debugging?

```
foreach($xml->Event as $event) {
    echo '<li><a href="', $event->link, '">';
        echo '<strong>', $event->title, '</strong>';
        echo '<span>', $event->beginDate, ' at ', $event->beginTime, '</span>';
        echo $event->location;
    echo '</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
foreach($xml->Event as $event) {
    echo '<li><a href="', $event->link, '">';
        echo '<strong>', $event->title, '</strong>';
        echo '<span>', $event->beginDate, ' at ', $event->beginTime, '</span>';
        echo $event->location;
    echo '</a></li>' . "\n";
}
```

Just add `. "\n"` to the last line in your loop.

Comment: It should be noted that the \n must be between *double quotes*. A single quote (aka apostrophe) will not work.

Answer (score 4):

Use new line '\n' or `PHP_EOL` at end of each line

Answer (score 3):

Try modifying the final line to include a line break:

```
echo '</a></li>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: It should be noted that ``PHP_EOL`` does NOT have to be used when outputting HTML code (as it is OS specific and the line breaks may show up properly on a Unix machine but not on a Windows machine)

Answer (score 3):

Append all of your strings with either `"\n"` (make sure you use double-quotes), or `PHP_EOL`.

```
echo '</a></li>' . "\n";
// or
echo '</a></li>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n`.

```
foreach($xml->Event as $event) {
    echo '<li><a href="', $event->link, '">' . "\n";
        echo '<strong>', $event->title, '</strong>' . "\n";
        echo '<span>', $event->beginDate, ' at ', $event->beginTime, '</span>' . "\n";
        echo $event->location . "\n";
    echo '</a></li> . "\n"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write the code like this:

```
<?php foreach($xml->Event as $event) { ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $event->link; ?>">
        <strong><?php echo $event->title; ?></strong>
        <span><?php echo $event->beginDate; ?> at <?php echo $event->beginTime; ?></span>
        <?php echo $event->location; ?>
    </a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Just curious, does this approach result in better performance? Or is it just a more standard way of coding the php portions?

Comment: @Ryan - Don't know about the performance difference (probably nothing to worry about) or if it is more standard. To me however it reads better. I never echo HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Add a '\n' at the end of each line you want to break.

```
foreach($xml->Event as $event) {
    echo '<li><a href="', $event->link, '">\n';
        echo '<strong>', $event->title, '</strong>\n';
        echo '<span>', $event->beginDate, ' at ', $event->beginTime, '</span>\n';
        echo $event->location;
    echo '</a></li>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Make sure you format your response such that code is block-indented in markdown.

Comment: This wouldn't work as you wrote it.  Only the last `\n` would work as expected since it's in quotes.  The previous ones would print the literal string `\n` due to the single quotes.